# Where does the Linux kernel allocate a useable port to the client for TCP/UDP

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I already know how TCP/UDP send/receive sockets in the linkage like `tcp_sendmsg()->tcp_transmit_skb()->ip_queue_xmit()`, but I haven't find where does the kernel allocate a useable port to the client. Since port is only useful for transmission layer, I think it must be here or there, but I haven't see it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks for any help.